# JavaScript libraries to visualize CityJSON data

Tags: javascript, software-recommendations

I am looking for JavaScript libraries that allow you to visualise cityJSON (https://www.cityjson.org/) data.

I am currently using cityGML with Cesium JS (https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/), but would like to switch to cityJSON, due to its reduced file size and easier-to-read structure.

Any hints?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Give this library a try: https://github.com/cityjson/ninja
It is a web viewer for CityJSON files